# Анимация ухода сайтбара

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Есть сайтбар , его выдвижение и задвижение нужно анимировать , но с помощью свойства animation получается только первое (анимация выдвижения)
Нужно что бы при наведении на кнопку  показывался сайтбар а при исчезновении навидения сайтбар прятался так же с анимацией.
Желательно только на css.

```
<body>
     <div class="buttom">
         <div class="saitbar"></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Можно использовать переходы (transition) вместо анимации.

2) В состоянии покоя боковой панели задавайте начальное смещение

3) При наведении на кнопку, смещение уберите. И меню плавно выедет. А когда уберете курсор, снова вернется к начальному положению

Пример:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
        
    background: #ee0a2e;

    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: 0.5s;
}
button:hover + .sidebar {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<button>Открыть меню</button>
<ul class="sidebar"></ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо , помог !

Comment: @ДмитрийХватов, да не за что. Если помогло, можете пометить ответ решением вопроса.

Comment: Я здесь недавно , а как это сделать?)0))

Comment: Я уже понял    .......